# Get the username of logged in user in SharePoint and use it instantly

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, com

I am able to get the full name of currently logged in user in SharePoint SitePage. However, I need to use the full name right after it and do something with it. Unfortunately, it's not working as expected.

Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentUser = "";
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        AddItem();
        alert(currentUser);
    });

    function AddItem()
    {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();

        context.load(this.user);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
    }
    function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
        currentUser = this.user.get_title();
        //alert(' Name:' + this.user.get_title() + '\n Login:' + this.user.get_loginName());
    }
    function onFaiureMethod(sender, args) {
        //alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```

Now I am thinking, since I am calling alert(currentUser) after AddItem(), I would get the name of currently logged in user, but it's not the case as it's giving me empty string. Basically alert(currentUser) is being called before AddItem().

Any ideas/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what sharepoint is (some ancient microsoft platform I seem to recall), but I do think I can tell you what the problem is.

AddItem does an asynchronous action, meaning that it initially doesn't do a lot and the alert get's triggered before the AddItem function triggers. So what you probably would want is something along the lines of:

```
var currentUser = "";
$(document).ready(function() { 
    AddItem(function(){
        alert(currentUser);
    });
});

function AddItem(callback)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();

    context.load(this.user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args) {
         currentUser = this.user.get_title();
         callback();
         //alert(' Name:' + this.user.get_title() + '\n Login:' + this.user.get_loginName());
    }),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
}
function onFaiureMethod(sender, args) {
    //alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Got an error saying "callback" is not defined. Please let me know if the error seems obvious to you. 

I just need a way to execute some code after the async call.

Comment: The indentation of your original question was extremely messed up, so I mistook the onSuccessmethod to be in the same scope. (fixed the indentation in the original question as well)